# Nuget package installation issue in VS2019 + Dotnet Framework 4.7.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am getting an error when trying to install nuget package in .net framework 4.7.2 application:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\PP\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.OpenFile(String path, FileAccess access, SafeFileHandle& handle)
   at System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path, DateTime lastWriteTimeUtc)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageFolderReader.CopyFiles(String destination, IEnumerable`1 packageFiles, ExtractPackageFileDelegate extractFile, ILogger logger, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageReaderBase.CopyFilesAsync(String destination, IEnumerable`1 packageFiles, ExtractPackageFileDelegate extractFile, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageExtractor.<ExtractPackageAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.ProjectManagement.FolderNuGetProject.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<InstallPackageAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.ProjectManagement.MSBuildNuGetProject.<InstallPackageAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteInstallAsync>d__85.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__75.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__74.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<PerformActionImplAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.9362158
========== Finished ==========
```

Env. Details:

Name             : Package Manager Host
Version          : 5.4.0.6292
Visual Studio 2019 version: 16.4.5
Application version: .Net Framework version 4.7.2

Steps tried so far:

1. I have restarted my machine and tried again but still the same issue.
2. Able to install the nuget package successfully in blank dotnet framework project.

Comment: Your question looks very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202946/nuget-dll-is-used-by-another-process. 
 There are some good points to try on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49229958/11820711

Comment: Also you can look at which process has a lock on this file using either PowerShell: https://superuser.com/a/1203347, or SysInternals: https://serverfault.com/a/1980

Answer (score 1):

> The process cannot access the file 'xxxxxxxNewtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   because it is being used by another process.

As the error said, the nuget package is controled by another process. You can try these steps:

**1)** first delete the all nuget packages in the global nuget cache under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages` or use [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

Also, delete the `packages` folder under your solution path(like `D:\PP\`).

**2)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder.

**3)** If you find `msbuild.exe` and `devenv.exe` in process explorer, please kill them.

**4)** disable antivirus for the moment

**5)** restart your project in VS, and try step 3 and then  run restore(Right-click on the solution-->`Restore Nuget Packages`) to restore the installed packages and then try to install `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package again.

Comment: In addition, please try to delete all files under  `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache` or disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` to test whether any extensions affect this behavior. Also, check whether there is any Antivirus protection procedure, if so, please try to turn off it in case it occupies the project.